# Significance and applications of the Riesz Representation Theorem in locally compact Hausdorff spaces

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure, riesz-representation-theorem

Can anyone tell me the signification of Theorem $2.14$ (The Riesz Representation Theorem in locally compact Hausdorff spaces), page $40, 41$ in Rudin - Real and Complex Analysis? And some applications of that theorem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: A few pages later, he uses this theorem to construct Lebesgue measure by considering the positive functional that is Riemann integration; a lot of the nicest properties drop out pretty quickly. Many other authors proceed through some variant of outer measure, instead.

Comment: Extremely significant! It tells you that (together with some results in chatper 6) the dual space of $C_0(X)$ is the space of Borel regular measure. Also in chapter 6 you have a neat representation of measure.

Comment: I can even remember what theorem 2.14 is without looking at your description......

Comment: The construction/proof of the Borel functional calculus for bounded operators would become seemingly harder without Riesz' representation theorem...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a summary of what have been said in the comments (by user61527, John Ma and Freeze_S):

1. Rudin uses the theorem a few pages later to construct Lebesgue measure by considering the positive functional that is Riemann integration; a lot of the nicest properties drop out pretty quickly. Many other authors proceed through some variant of outer measure, instead;
2. The theorem is very significant, because together with results from Chapter 6 tells you that the dual space of $C_0(X)$ is the space of Borel regular measure;
3. The construction and the proof of the Borel functional calculus for bounded operators would become harder without the theorem.